# Go to NavLink when onKeyDown function is run

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, react-router-dom

I have a `<NavLink />` which I am trying to make meet accessibility standards. This link opens up a new component from within the current page.

I want the NavLink to be visited when I press the 'enter' key.

In my NavLink I have the following onKeyDown:

```
onKeyDown={() => {
    this.toggleViaEnter('1'); // '1' refers to section 1
}}
```

I want it to take a parameter that is the section number, and also the event as I only want to toggle this section if the key press was **enter**.

Here is my function:

```
toggleViaEnter(tab, event) {
  console.log('char', event.keyCode);
  if(event.keyCode === 13) {
    this.toggle(tab);
  }
}
```

I am trying to log out the keyCode so that I can see that it is '13', however in my console I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined

I think this means that I'm not passing the event into `toggleViaEnter` - I am unsure how to pass multiple parameters including the event into a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the event to `toggleViaEnter`. To do that, update `onKeyDown` to take the event and pass it

```
onKeyDown={event => {
    this.toggleViaEnter('1', event); // '1' refers to section 1
}}
```

---

You could also update the `toggleViaEnter` to return a function like so

```
toggleViaEnter = tab => event => {
  console.log('char', event.keyCode);
  if(event.keyCode === 13) {
    this.toggle(tab);
  }
}
```

And you would update `onKeyDown` to be

```
onKeyDown={this.toggleViaEnter('1')}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your issue.

```
onKeyDown={(e) => {
    this.toggleViaEnter('1', e); // '1' refers to section 1
}}
```